# C# - Killing a process by a part of it's name

Tags: c#

I'm searching for how to do it in C#, like this :

```
foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("cheatengine-x86_64"))
{
    proc.Kill();
}
```

I am using this statement, but there are different versions of the program, like just cheatengine or cheatengine-x86, I'd like to close any of these, by starting with the name 'cheat', or just 'cheate', just to avoid the older versions.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Obviously, you have tried the code you posted, but what I have done outside of that?

Comment: Be aware that all a user needs to do to work around such code is to rename the cheat tool's .exe file.

Comment: Yes thanks for the reply. This is just an educational interest, actually I am working on this study to make a bigger project. Thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 16):

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;

Process.GetProcesses()
    .Where(x => x.ProcessName.StartsWith("cheate", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => x.Kill());
```

Comment: Pet peeve: don't use ToLower to do case-insensitive comparison, that's useless string allocations. Use the StringComparison parameter (probably want OrdinalIgnoreCase) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith#System_String_StartsWith_System_String_System_StringComparison_

Comment: Absolutely correct, not sure why I would have done that. I'll have to go back to 2013 and ask the question. And also warn myself about some bad stuff coming over the next 8 years. Fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

You can iterate through each process name, then match it with a regexp and then kill it if it matches.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"cheate.*");
 foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses(".")){
    if(regex.Matches(p.ProcessName))
      p.Kill();
 }
```

something like this.

The advantage of this is, you can kill any process that starts with or ends with a particular regular expression.

Comment: That needs to be `@"cheate.*"` in the regex.

Comment: it should be ```if(regex.Match(p.ProcessName).Success)```

Answer (score 4):

adapted from here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/get-a-list-of-running-processes-in-c/

```
using System.Diagnostics;


Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process theprocess in processlist)
{

    if(theprocess.ProcessName.StartsWith("cheat");
         theprocess.Kill(); 
}
```

This is just a rough idea, you can use any method you want to match the process. I recommend something that ignores case, but I would be very cautious with false positives. I would not be happy with your program if it closed something it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Process.GetProcesses()` and use Linq to filter the ones that you want to kill.

Comment: Small typo: at the end of your if the semicolon should be replaced by a  )

Answer (score -1):

This will kill the process when it contains specific string

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
                         .Where(x => x.ProcessName.ToLower()
                                      .Contains("chrome"))
                         .ToList()
                         .ForEach(x => x.Kill());
```

Comment: A copy of the top-voted answer but with a less relevant specific string, please remove this.