# How can I keep a handle on System.Diagnostics.Process.start?

Tags: c#

I opened an explorer instance via

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @<path>);
```

however, I also want to close this exact process at a given time.

I tried this so far:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.Start("explorer.exe", @<path>);
```

However, that doesn't seem to work at all. This is what I'm getting when I try it that way:

> "Member '' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"

I am fairly sure it's something pretty simple, but I can't get around it...

Any help?

Comment: check if process exists then terminate it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345363/kill-some-processes-by-exe-file-name, the `at a given time` is up to you how you implement it!

Comment: If you mean stopping the process, Simply you use proc.Kill

Comment: Yes, but I can't even get the proc.Start to work. I get this error message: "Member '<method>' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"

Comment: The error clearly indicates that you shouldn't be creating a reference of Process for calling the start method. Call the start method with Type (System.Diagnostic) which will return the Process and then you can do operations like proc.Kill()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the `Process` using `ProcessStartInfo`:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe", @"C:\some.file");
Process p = Process.Start(psi);

///

p.Kill();
```

Call `Kill` on the process when you want to.

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` returns `Process`

```
var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @<path>); 
proc.Kill();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you had is that that the method [Process.Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx) is a `static` method and does not need an instance of the `Process` class to be called.

As others have said, `Start()` returns a `Process` object that you can then work with and can call `Kill()` later on at some point.