# Can't kill a process with name with spaces

Tags: c#, kill-process

I got this in my Main Class(the program is a patcher exe..):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // in the exe.dat is written this(the name of the running exe file): KF2 DSM.exe
    string FileName = File.ReadAllText("exe.dat"); 

    // this SHOULD kill the process BUT it doesn't! btw i also treid this: Process.Start("taskkill", "/F /IM " + '"' + FileName + '"');, and still nothing
    Process.Start("taskkill", "/F /IM " + FileName); 

    File.Delete(FileName);

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile("https://onedrive.live.com/download?resid=763D7D60E7D1759D!328&authkey=!AArR3IwAehnZ3gc&ithint=file%2cexe", FileName);

        while(client.IsBusy)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    File.Delete("exe.dat");

    Process.Start(FileName);
}
```

I added some notes in the code for you.

I tried almost EVERY syntaxes/codes for killing a process, but none of them worked!

Is there another way to kill a process that would work for me?

Comment: You need to escape the spaces. Otherwise it appears as two arguments to taskkill. Also, don't shell out to taskkill. Look into the Process class' other methods.

Comment: I tried all that before

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kill some processes by .exe file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345363/kill-some-processes-by-exe-file-name)

Comment: Use `\"` between the process name to allow spaces, it's basically creating a single argument instead of multiple separated by spaces.

Comment: how am I supposed to use that? -.-

Comment: btw, DownloadFile is a sync call, you can't wait for it with IsBusy

Comment: Process.Start("taskkill", "/F /IM \"" + FileName+"\"");

Comment: but, maybe people should stop using spaces, uppercase letters, dashes, slashes, prans, brackets and underlines in their exe/process name, what is wrong with "app.exe" that can be fixed with "My App.exe"?

Comment: i can see ERROR in the console that opens

Comment: try KF2 DSM without .exe extension

Comment: even without .exe extension

Comment: OOH it was because when you run the program from the studio, the process has .vhost.exe after the name -.- (I'm on Win10 so i Couldn't tell until I looked into process browsing in cheatengine....)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Process.GetProcessesByName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx) and [`Process.Kill`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx):

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(FileName)) {
    process.Kill();
}
```

Comment: Uh-huh. In what way does it not work? Error? Doesn't find process? Doesn't kill process?