# Session Kill or release In HP service manager

Tags: c#

How can I kill or release session of hp service manager after retrieve data using wsdl call.

For Connection My code is here

```
      try
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
            EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("*****");

            IncidentManagementClient IM = new IncidentManagementClient(binding, address);

            IM.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "*****";
            IM.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "****";

            return IM;

        }
```

This code create session successfully but how can i release session after retrieve data from Service manager.

Please answer code in C#

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrap it in a using statement with the connection?

```
using(var client = new IncidentManagementClient ())
{

}
```

Since it disposes the connection at the end of the using statement

Comment: Dear , I need how to terminate/kill/release process using c# code, this above my code works fine for create process or session

Comment: I explain more my question,
I just connect to service manager using some wsdl after complete my work on sm how can i disconnect so my user release from sm.

Comment: I will have to look at it more when I get home. Sorry, I am out currently. I'll be home in an hour.

Comment: Are you interested to replay ?

Answer (score 0):

As in [Kill some processes by .exe file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345363/kill-some-processes-by-exe-file-name)
you can kill the sm process by the following:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("sm"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

But next time, the sm process will not be available and you have to start it. The web service will fail if you didn't started sm again.

Normally you should keep sm process running and don't care to kill it.