# How to close Apps only in windows by C#?

Tags: c#, process

I try to close running user apps (Application Programs) in windows by C# like word, forxitReader, whatsApp , etc.

I try to make a desktop App to secure an online exam like Safe Exam Browser.

My senario is:

1 - get the process of them only as a list (not System programs.)

2 - Kill them by Process.kill();

[image]

But I don't know how to do the first step.

How can I get a list of these programs only?

Comment: [Have you tried this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345363/kill-some-processes-by-exe-file-name)

Comment: This question is about how to kill the process by the name of process. But my question is about how to get a list of all user apps only.

Comment: I want to generate a list with the names of apps in the image.

Comment: Who's computer do you plan on running this on? Your company's computers? Run the computer in [Kiosk Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/kiosk-mode/kiosk-mode). You don't have the right to kill processes that don't belong to your program on someone else's computer.